# Probability teams from the same country play each other in Champions League Round of 16, Quarter Final and Semi-Final

Tags: probability-theory

thanks for your help. I state first that I am not a mathematician and probability has never been my strong point, so please forgive if the question is strange.

I have 16 clubs that can be drawn against each other in the UCL Round of 16 as follows: Spain 3, Germany 4, England 4, Italy 1, France 1, Russia 1, Turkey 1, Greece 1.

First, I would like to calculate, for each country, the probability that two teams from the same country are drawn against each other (e.g. for Spain, what is the probability that the Spanish clubs are drawn against each other?). The reasoning should explain the obvious result that this probability would be 0 for Italy, France, Russia, Turkey and Greece.

Secondly, I would like to know the probability that at least two teams from the same market play each other.

Thirdly, I have to perform the same exercise on the quarter final.

Many thanks again and best regards.

Comment: Barca looked good against Juventus.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question:

I just ran a Monte Carlo simulation and got an empirical estimate of about 0.873.

My Python code for this is below.

As to your second question, please clarify. What are teams "from the same market"?

Monte Carlo simulation code (Python):

`import numpy as np
import itertools
#
teams = range(16)
#
numtrials = 1000000
same_country = 0
for i in range(numtrials):
    p = np.random.permutation(teams)
    if p[0] in (1, 2) or p[1] in (0, 2) or p[2] in (0, 1): 
        same_country += 1
    elif (p[3] in (4, 5, 6) or p[4] in (3, 5, 6) 
          or p[5] in (3, 4, 6) or p[6] in (3, 4, 5)): 
        same_country += 1
    elif (p[7] in (8, 9, 10) or p[8] in (7, 9, 10) 
          or p[9] in (7, 8, 10) or p[10] in (7, 8, 9)): 
        same_country += 1
#
print 'Probability of same team = ', same_country / float(numtrials)`